# How to Check Success and Failure message from login form by using selenium?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

The following code is using for g-mail login.

> ```
> package gmail_Login;
> import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
> import org.junit.After;
> import org.junit.Before;
> import org.junit.Test;
> import org.openqa.selenium.By;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
> import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
>
> public class Login {
>
> //public static void main(String[] args) {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>   // created reference variable for WebDriver
>      WebDriver drv;
>      @Before
>      public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
>             // initializing drv variable using FirefoxDriver
>             drv=new FirefoxDriver();
>             // launching gmail.com on the browser
>             drv.get("https://gmail.com");
>             // maximized the browser window
>             drv.manage().window().maximize();
>             drv.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
>      }
>      @Test
>      public void test() throws InterruptedException {
>             // saving the GUI element reference into a "username" variable of WebElement type
>             WebElement username = drv.findElement(By.id("Email"));
>             // entering username
>             username.sendKeys("fake mail id");
>            // clicking next button
>             drv.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
> ```
>
> }

I have to given fake id then click on next button error message is coming, but how to check error message.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did you think you can implement this scenario?

Comment: I don't know it's possible or not, so I can asked that question. This is not possible?

Comment: There are lot of ways by which you can do this. It depends on the requirement and behaviour of the site. If you enter wrong username and password. It will prompt you with the error message. The `error message` that you are getting is a `WebElement` you can verify its `presence` to validate its a `Failure` scenario. If the login is successful you would be redirected to a new page. There you can verify the `Title` or `URL` or `Some Text` to validate its a successful scenario. Its upto you how you go and implement the scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on next button get text of error message using below steps:

1. Find the error message element

   WebElement msg=driver.findElement(By.id("errormsg_0_Email"));
2. Get text of msg

   String text=msg.getText();
3. Assert/Verify the text with expected text

   Assert.assertEquals(text,expectedText);